# What is the dual norm of infinity norm ball with a non-unity radius?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

The dual norm of an infinity norm ball with a *unit* radius can be expressed as

$$\|x\|_1 = \underset{y \in \mathbb{R}^n,\|y\|_{\infty} \le {\color{blue}1}}{\sup }x^Ty$$

What is a dual norm of a *non-unity* radius, ${\color{red} \lambda \geq 1}$, infinity norm ball? Is it the following?

$${\color{red} \lambda}\|x\|_1 = \underset{y \in \mathbb{R}^n,\|y\|_{\infty} \le {\color{red} \lambda}}{\sup }x^Ty$$

If so, how to prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\sup_{\|y\|_{\infty} \le \lambda} x^{T}y
=\sup_{\|\frac y {\lambda}\|_{\infty} \le 1} \lambda x^{T} \frac y {\lambda},
$$ which can be written as
$\sup_{\|z\|_{\infty} \leq 1} \lambda x^{T} z$ or
$$\lambda \sup_{\|z\|_{\infty} \leq 1} x^{T}z = \lambda \|x\|_1.$$